# Check duplicate email from server in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, express

I am working in MERN project. i am inserting form data in my database. I Have successfully inserted all form data.

*But i want check that if any user is going to register duplicate email should give error to user*

**The error i am getting in vscode terminal**

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\kridhatutor\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\kridhatutor\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\kridhatutor\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\kridhatutor\server\router\Auth.js:105:37
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

**And in my browser i am getting --"Email already exist"--**

**For this I have tried this**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        let email = req.body.email;
        let path = `C:/Users/kumar/Desktop/kridhatutor/server/images/${email}`;
        fs.mkdirsSync(path);
        cb(null, path);
        // cb(null, 'images');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);

    }
});


const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    const allowedFileTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'];
    if (allowedFileTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
}

let upload = multer({ storage, fileFilter });

router.post('/teacherregister', upload.fields([{
    name: "profilephoto", maxCount: 1
}, {
    name: "identityphoto", maxCount: 1
},
{
    name: "tenthphoto", maxCount: 1
},
{
    name: "twelvephoto", maxCount: 1
},
{
    name: "latestphoto", maxCount: 1
}
]), (req, res) => {
    

    const names = req.body.names
    const phone = req.body.phone
    const email = req.body.email
    const city = req.body.city
    const address = req.body.address
    const comfortable = req.body.comfortable
    const classesyoutake = req.body.classesyoutake
    const subjectsyoutake = req.body.subjectsyoutake
    const teachingexprienceinyears = req.body.teachingexprienceinyears
    const exprienceteaching = req.body.exprienceteaching
    const profilephoto = req.files['profilephoto'][0]
    const identityphoto = req.files['identityphoto'][0]
    const tenthphoto = req.files['tenthphoto'][0]
    const twelvephoto = req.files['twelvephoto'][0]
    const latestphoto = req.files['latestphoto'][0]


    try {
        const userEx = TECAHER.findOne({ email: email })
        if (userEx) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: "Email already exit" })
            // alert("email already exit")
        }
            const newUserData = {
                names,
                phone,
                email,
                city,
                address,
                comfortable,
                classesyoutake,
                subjectsyoutake,
                teachingexprienceinyears,
                exprienceteaching,
                profilephoto,
                identityphoto,
                tenthphoto,
                twelvephoto,
                latestphoto
        
        
            }
        
            const newUser = new TECAHER(newUserData);
                  newUser.save()
                    .then(() => res.json('User Added'))
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
        
       
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

})



//STUDENT--PARENT register

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const { identity, names, phone, email, city, address, subject, classes, message } = req.body
    // if (!identity || !names || !phone || !email || !city || !address || !subject || !classes || !message) {
    //     return res.status(422).json({ error: "Please mark all the field" })
    // }

    try {
        const userExit = await User.findOne({ email: email })
        if (userExit) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: "Email already exit" })
            // alert("email already exit")

        }
        // else if (password != cpassword) {
        //     return res.status(422).json({ error: "password and confirm password don not match" })
        // }

        const user = new User({ identity, names, phone, email, city, address, subject, classes, message })
        await user.save()
        res.status(201).json({ message: "user registered successfulluy" })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

})
```

*How to check that condition?*

*Thankyou*

Answer (score 1):

After sending the error message, you must return from your function:

```js
if (userEx) {
  res.status(400).json({ error: "Email already exists" });
  return;
}
```

Otherwise, the rest of the function will be executed, which leads to another message ("User added") being sent. But you can use `res.json` at most once per request, otherwise you will get the observed error.

Comment: Now i am getting this ```FormData {  }

Object { error: "Email already exit" }```

Comment: Put `return` before every res statement